# FreeBSD Ports Broken -- Python Issue? Portmaster -a

Tags: freebsd, python, pkg-config

Upgraded FreeBSD from 8.2 >> 8.4 >> 10.0-RELEASE today. In the process, I believe I have mangled my ports tree quite badly and am having issues upgrading/reinstalling ports (as the upgrade asks me to do).

As stands, I think it may have something to do with Python but I'm not sure where to go from here.

Upgrading ports fails here.

```
#portname -a

===>>> Port directory: /usr/ports/lang/python2

make: "/usr/ports/Mk/bsd.python.mk" line 558: Malformed conditional (${PYTHON_REL} >= 320 && defined(PYTHON_PY3K_PLIST_HACK))
make: Fatal errors encountered -- cannot continuemake: "/usr/ports/Mk/bsd.python.mk" line 558: Malformed conditional (${PYTHON_REL} >= 320 && defined(PYTHON_PY3K_PLIST_HACK))
make: Fatal errors encountered -- cannot continue===>>> Launching 'make checksum' for lang/python2 in background
make: "/usr/ports/Mk/bsd.python.mk" line 558: Malformed conditional (${PYTHON_REL} >= 320 && defined(PYTHON_PY3K_PLIST_HACK))
make: Fatal errors encountered -- cannot continue
```

More info:

```
# less /etc/make.conf
# added by use.perl 2014-01-27 15:35:31
PERL_VERSION=5.10.1
WITH_PKGNG=yes

# python -V
Python 2.6.6

# uname -a
FreeBSD herp.derp.herp l 10.0-RELEASE FreeBSD 10.0-RELEASE #0 r260789: Thu Jan 16 22:34:59 UTC 2014     root@snap.freebsd.org:/usr/obj/usr/src/sys/GENERIC  amd64
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would appear you have a very old ports tree, probably installed with 8.2. The current default version for perl is 5.16 and python is 2.7. In fact perl 5.10 isn't even available to install any more. There have been many recent ports updates specifically to build on FreeBSD 10.0 that you will need to start building any ports.

The easiest way to update your ports tree would be `portsnap fetch extract`. You may want to delete the old ports tree first to make sure you don't have any old files left over. Any port management tools, like portmaster, will then need to be updated manually before you use them for updating your other ports.

FreeBSD 10.0 also uses the new pkgng system that you may be unfamiliar with [Read this for more info](http://www.freebsd.org/doc/en_US.ISO8859-1/books/handbook/pkgng-intro.html). Previously you would use `pkg_info -Ix perl5` now you would use `pkg info -Ix perl5` Also for binary package installs, `pkg_add -r lang/perl5.16` has been replaced with `pkg install lang/perl5.16`.

Comment: Thanks, Sambler -- it does seem like I have an old ports tree -- is there a guide on how to rebuild your ports tree using 10? The change to pkg has confused me and I can't find much.

Comment: The pkg commands aren't a big change from the old pkg_* style commands, just a slight syntax change. While pkg mainly aims at binary installs, you can disable the repositories and `pkg install` should then fall back to compiling from ports tree (or do a binary upgrade to get started). Edit `/etc/pkg/FreeBSD.conf` to disable the official repository. `pkg info -aoq | xargs pkg install -f` should re-install everything for you.